# oracle greatest of two arithmetic expression values

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, arithmetic-expressions

I need to find greatest of two arithmetic expression for the below case,but its returning the result of first expression alone.its not getting the greatest among the two.any suggestions please.

```
SELECT greatest((((Received*8) + (Received*56))/(1000*900*64000*900)),
                  (((Transmitted*8) + (Transmitted*56))/(1000*900*64000*900))) AS Greatest_value
FROM Table_name
```

Result i got: arithmetic exp result of first expression

Comment: Wat are the values for Received and Transmitted in your case?

Comment: its a dynamic value,changing each time

Answer (score 3):

Since the multipliers are the same for both values being compared, you can simplify the code to:

```
SELECT GREATEST( Received, Transmitted ) * ( (8+56)/(1000*900*6400*900) )
         AS Greatest_value
FROM   table_name
```

Or just:

```
SELECT GREATEST( Received, Transmitted ) / 810000000000
         AS Greatest_value
FROM   table_name
```

Apart from that you would need to check your data:

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN Received >= Transmitted THEN 1 END ) AS received_greater,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN Received <  Transmitted THEN 1 END ) AS transmitted_greater
FROM   table_name;
```